# Proving there do not exist natural numbers $m$ and $n$ such that $7m^2=n^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-factorization

I'm stuck on my proof of this concept and I could use some help on understanding what to do next.

> Prove there do not exist natural numbers $m$ and $n$ such that $7m^2=n^2$

Proof will be by contradiction. So, assume there does exist natural numbers such that $7m^2=n^2$ is true.

Let $m=p_1^{r_1} p_2^{r_2 }…p_k^{r_k}$ and $n=p_1^{t_1} p_2^{t_2}…p_s^{t_s}$

Then $m^2=(p_1^{r_1} p_2^{r_2 }…p_k^{2r_k})^2=p_1^{2r_1} p_2^{2r_2 }…p_k^{2r_k}$ and $n^2=(p_1^{t_1} p_2^{t_2}…p_s^{t_s})^2=p_1^{2t_1} p_2^{2t_2}…p_s^{2t_s}$

Substitute this into $7m^2=n^2$ to obtain,

$7(p_1^{2r_1} p_2^{2r_2 }…p_k^{2r_k})=p_1^{2t_1} p_2^{2t_2}…p_s^{2t_s}$

The idea is that all values of m and n chosen to satisfy $7m^2=n^2$ are natural numbers so they therefore can be expressed as a product of primes.

This is where I'm stuck. How do I go about showing the contradiction?

Thanks for the help

Comment: If two numbers are equal, then they have the same number of prime factors, counting multiplicity (because they're the same number!) Figure out why the two sides of your equation cannot have the same number of prime factors.

Comment: It is easy because $7m^2$ must be a square.

Comment: This is not clear.  Are you allowed to use Unique Factorization?  If so, there is no difficulty ($7$ divides the left an odd number of times and it divides the right an even number of times).  But if you are, say, trying to mimic the classical argument that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational, then I'd have thought you wanted to avoid Unique Factorization.

Comment: "It is easy because $7m^2$ must be a square"  And why can't $7m^2$ be a square?  If $\sqrt 7= \frac ab$ and $b|m$ then we have $7m^2 = a^2(\frac mb)^2$?  Why can't that happen?

Comment: My textbook and professor want me to prove this question only using prime factorization, which is why I attempted the question with only that concept. But I do understand your logic for using the irrationality of root 7 to prove the question

Comment: Oh,.... the if you are allowed to assume every number has a unique prime factorization the $7m^2$ must have a prime factorization that includes $7$ to an odd power.  ANd $n^2$ can *not* have a prime factorization that includes $7$ to an odd power.

Comment: Why must $7m^2$ have a prime factorization that includes 7 to an odd power? Do you simply mean $7^1$? How did you relate this to your statement that $n^2$ can not have a prime factorization that includes $7$ to an odd power? I'm struggling with this question because there are concepts I'm supposed to automatically see and understand, but I don't and they aren't being explained.

Comment: Okay.  $0$ is an even number.  $1$ is an odd number.  What ever the prime factors of $m$ or $n$ are, $n^2, m^2$ will have the same factors to *twice* the powers, i.e. to an even power.  So $m^2$ and $n^2$ must have $7$ to an even (maybe $0$, but even) power. So if $m^2$ has $7$ to an even (maybe $0$) power then $7m^2$ will have it to one higher power (maybe just $1$) and one higher than an even power is an odd power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let $m=p_1^{r_1} p_2^{r_2 }…p_k^{r_k}$ and $n=p_1^{t_1} p_2^{t_2}…p_s^{t_s}$

Your indexes here are the same implying that $n$ and $m$ have the same prime factors.

Better to write this as $m=p_{a_1}^{r_1} p_{a_2}^{r_2 }…p_{a_k}^{r_k}$ and $n=p_{b_1}^{t_1} p_{b_2}^{t_2 }…p_{b_s}^{t_s}$.

> Substitute this into $7m^2=n^2$ to obtain, $7(p_1^{2r_1} p_2^{2r_2 }…p_k^{2r_k})=p_1^{2t_1} p_2^{2t_2}…p_s^{2t_s}$

Okay that means that there is a $7$ on the LHS so there must be a $7$ on the RHS.  So  one of the $p_{b_i}$ must be equal to $7$.  Without loss of generality let's assume that $p_{b_1} = 7$ then we have

> $7m^2 = 7p_{a_1}^{2r_1} p_{2a_2}^{2r_2 }…p_{a_k}^{2r_k}=n^2 = 7^{2t_1} p_{2b_2}^{2t_2 }…p_{b_s}^{2t_s}$

Now $2t_1 \ne 1$ and $2t_1 > 1$ so that $7$ on the LHS can't be the only $7$ in the factorization of $7m^2$.  So one of the $p_{a_1}$ must be $7$.  Without loss of generality let's assume that $p_{b_1} = 7$.   then we have

$7m^2 = 7\cdot 7^{2r_1}  p_{2a_2}^{2r_2 }…p_{a_k}^{2r_k}=7^{2r_1 + 1} p_{2a_2}^{2r_2 }…p_{a_k}^{2r_k}=n^2 = 7^{2t_1} p_{2b_2}^{2t_2 }…p_{b_s}^{2t_s}$

But that means $2r_1 + 1 = 2t_1$.  But that's impossible as $2r_1 + 1$ is odd and $2t_1$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

The power of $7$ in the decomposition of $7m^2$ in prime numbers is odd, whereas the power of $7$ in the decomposition of $n^2$ in prime numbers is even.

Comment: Forgive me for how basic this question will be, how are we able to consider the power of $7$ for the decomposition of $n^2$ in prime numbers? $7$ is only on the LHS, not the RHS.

Comment: @BobbyB The power can be $0$, if $7$ does not appear in the decomposition of $n$ in prime factors !

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not able to understand the logic you're going for. I need a more explicit explanation. I'm very bad at understanding these sort of concepts.

Comment: @BobbyB Just look at the prime factorization of the number : if $7$ appears in it, then you can look at its power ; if $7$ does not appear, then you can say that it appears with the power $0$...

Comment: Okay...I still don't understand. Is there anyway you can relate this vague worded concept to an explicit statement using my format presented in the question? I have, $7(p_1^{2r_1} p_2^{2r_2 }…p_k^{2r_k})=p_1^{2t_1} p_2^{2t_2}…p_s^{2t_s}$. How do I go about showing whatever you stated using the prime factorization I've created?

Comment: Just look if one of the $p_i$'s or if one of the $p'_i$'s is $7$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $(m,n)$ solution then $(\lambda n,\lambda m)$ is also solution, so without loss of generality we can suppose $\gcd(n,m)=1$.

Now since $7\mid 7m^2\implies 7\mid n^2$ and since $7$ prime $\implies 7\mid n$

Then $n=7n'$ and $7m^2=(7n')^2\iff m^2=7n'^2$.

But with a similar process then $7\mid m$ which is a contradiction since $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Therefore no solutions except the trivial one $(0,0)$ exists.